# Why is C++ behaving weirdly when I add leading 0's to an int?

Tags: c++

Why is

```
cout << 0110 << endl;
```

printing out 72?

I didnt' think adding leading 0's to an int would make any difference, shouldn't '0110' be the same as '110'?

Comment: The leading 0 denotes the number to be in octal representation. Yes, they were funny bones, those guys who invented programming languages last century...

Comment: And if you think that's hilarious, you won't guess what would happen if you prefix the number not just with a `0`, but with `0x`. What a riot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `0110` is an [octal-literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal):

> octal-literal is the digit zero (0) followed by zero or more octal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

That's why you're getting `72` when printing out it, it's not same as `110`.

Comment: @nilcit Is there some way this causes a problem for you? It only affects numbers in your source code, it doesn't affect input.

Comment: the way I'm conceputally thinking about something makes using the zero padded ints much more pleasant to work with

Comment: Unfortunately, some people a bit like you, but who thought counting in base 8 was very pleasant got to the standard committee first. :)

Comment: Semi-trolling but good point to think is: zero starts by zero... Happily 0=0 in both systems...

Answer (score 1):

The compiler's right.

With ONE leading zero, your number will be treated as 8-based, so `0110` means (110)<sub>8</sub>, which equals to (72)<sub>10</sub>.

If you try to write `08`, your compiler will complain it's not a valid octal number.